# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch'

Tags: tensorflow

I get the following error with the code `import tensorflow as tf`:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list'
```

Any ideas?

tensorboard                        2.4.0
tensorboard-data-server            0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.6.0
tensorflow                         2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.3.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem       0.23.1

Comment: Can you add the output of `pip list`?

Answer (score 2):

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`
works for me original I was using TensorFlow 2.6.0 and upgrade it to 2.7.0 and works fine.